# AWK for loop with two input files

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have the following files:

```
A-111.txt  
A-311.txt

B-111.txt  
B-311.txt


C-111.txt  
C-312.txt

 
D-112.txt  
D-311.txt
```

I want to merge lines of files with the same basename (same letter before the dash) if there is a match in column 4. I have many files so I want to do it in the loop.

So far I have this:

```
for f1 in *-1**.txt; do f2="${f1/-1/-3}"; awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NR==FNR { a[$4,$4]=$0 ; next } ($4,$4) in a { print a[$4,$4],$0 }' "$f1" "$f2" > $f1_merged.txt; done
```

It works for files A and B as intended, but not for files C and D files.
Can someone help me improve the code, please?

---

EDIT - here's the above code formatted legibly:

```
for f1 in *-1**.txt; do
    f2="${f1/-1/-3}"
    awk -F"\t" '
        BEGIN {
            OFS = FS
        }
        NR == FNR {
            a[$4, $4] = $0
            next
        }
        ($4, $4) in a {
            print a[$4, $4], $0
        }
    ' "$f1" "$f2" > $f1_merged.txt
done
```

---

EDIT - after Ed Morton kindly formatted my code, the error is:

```
awk: cmd. line:7: fatal: cannot open file 'C-311.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)

awk: cmd. line:7: fatal: cannot open file 'D-312.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

---

EDIT-all lines not only the first one should be compared
Input file A-111.txt

| ID | Chr | bp | db_SNP | REF | ALT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-111 | 1 | 4367323 | rs1490413 | G | A |
| A-111 | 1 | 12070292 | rs730123 | G | A |
| A-111 | 22 | 47836412 | rs2040411 | G | A |
| A-111 | 22 | 49876931 | rs4605480 | T | C |

Input file A-311.txt

| ID | Chr | bp | db_SNP | REF | ALT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-311 | Y | 17053771 | rs17269816 | C | T |
| A-311 | Y | 22665262 | rs2196155 | A | G |
| A-311 | 1 | 4367323 | rs1490413 | G | A |
| A-311 | 1 | 12070292 | rs730123 | G | A |

Desired output file

| ID | Chr | bp | db_SNP | REF | ALT | ID | Chr | bp | db_SNP | REF | ALT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-111 | 1 | 4367323 | rs1490413 | G | A | A-311 | 1 | 4367323 | rs1490413 | G | A |
| A-111 | 1 | 12070292 | rs730123 | G | A | A-311 | 1 | 12070292 | rs730123 | G | A |

Comment: do you understand why the `C` and `D` files aren't processed? if not, replace the `awk` call with `echo "$f1 : $f2"`, run the script and compare the filenames printed by the `echo` with the actual filenames; once you understand that issue you should be a bit closer to what you want to do; perhaps just look for files with the same matching prefix *before* the `-`? (assumes there will only be two files with the same prefix before the `-`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="ref_"                                   # prefix to declare array variable names
declare -A bases                                # array to count files for the basename
for f in *-[0-9]*.txt; do                       # loop over the target files
    base=${f%%-*}                               # extract the basename
    declare -n ref="$prefix$base"               # indirect reference to an array named "$base"
    ref+=("$f")                                 # create a list of filenames for the basename
    (( bases[$base]++ ))                        # count the number of files for the basename
done

for base in "${!bases[@]}"; do                  # loop over the basenames
    if (( ${bases[$base]} == 2 )); then         # check if the number of files are two
        declare -n ref="$prefix$base"           # indirect reference

        awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
        NR==FNR {                               # read 1st file
            f0[$4] = $0                         # store the record keyed by $4
            next
        }
        $4 in f0 {                              # read 2nd file and check if f0[$f4] is defined
            print f0[$4], $0                    # if match, merge the records and print
        }' "${ref[0]}" "${ref[1]}" > "${base}_merged.txt"
    fi
done
```

- First extract the basenames such as "A", "B", .. then create a list
  of associated filenames. For instance, the array "A" will be assigned to
  `('A-111.txt' 'A-311.txt')`. At the same time, the array `bases` counts
  the files for each basename.
- Then loop over the basenames, make sure the number of associated files
  are two, compare the 4th columns of the files. If they match, concatenate
  the files to generate a new file.
- The `awk` script searches the 4th field across the lines; if match, paste the lines of the two files.

Comment: Thanks, but it works only partially. Your code handles input files properly, but it concatenates the files to generate a new file if there is a match in the 4th column.
I want to merge lines from each file next to each other if there is a match in the 4th column. This is what the awk in my code does. 
But great code anyway!!!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated the script accordingly. Just replaced `cat` with `paste` command to merge lines side by side. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as intended!!! However, if I replace capital letters (I use them only for simplicity, my bad) in filenames with real names (6digit number e.g. 116119-111.txt) there is the following error: "bash: declare: `116119': invalid variable name for name reference". I am sorry bothering you again, but could update your script again to get rid of this, please? The prefix before dash is always 6digit number.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt testing and the feedback. Actually I had a feeling
that the basename "A", "B" .. might be simplified for the explanation purpose.
As the variable name "$ref" should be a valid bash variable name, it needs
to start with an alphabetical character (including an underscore) and
consists of alphanumerical characters. Now I have modified my code to put
a prefix before the basename digits. Would you please test it again? BR.

Comment: @Milos this answer only compares the first line of each file and ignores the rest, there's nothing in your question to suggest that's what you wanted to do but you accepted this answer so presumably it is what you wanted so please edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide examples of at least 2 "A-*" files you want compared and the expected output from that comparison so others reading this in future to find answers to similar problems can better understand it to see if it matches their problem.

Comment: Thank you, @EdMorton!!! This is very important info for me because I want to compare all lines not only the first one.

Comment: My bad! I had misunderstood the requirement. Thanks Ed Morton for clarifying the issue. I've fixed my code to compare multiple lines. BR.

Comment: No no, my bad, I should be more specific from the beginning. Thanks for your effort @tshiono. But your code prints only 1st line (header) after the last modification.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I did match the 4th fields only on the same line. Now the updated script matches them across the lines. I hope it will now meet the requirements. Cheers!.

Comment: Amazing!!! It works. Great job@tshiono. Thanks a lot for all your efforts once again!!!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Your update with sample input and the expected output was helpful. Cheers.